# How to use the child element attribute values in parent element using XSLT?

Tags: xslt

Input XML file:

```
<ce:index-entry id="ie0006">
  <ce:index-heading>Acceptance test</ce:index-heading>
  <ce:intra-ref id="ia0011" xlink:href="pii:B978-0-12-801507-0.00017-1#st0040">452–455</ce:intra-ref>
  <ce:intra-ref id="ia0012" xlink:href="pii:B978-0-12-801507-0.00017-1#sp0020">453<ce:italic>f</ce:italic></ce:intra-ref>
  <ce:intra-ref id="ia0013" xlink:href="pii:B978-0-12-801507-0.00017-1#sp0025">455<ce:italic>f</ce:italic></ce:intra-ref>
  <ce:intra-ref id="ia0014" xlink:href="pii:B978-0-12-801507-0.00017-1#st0055">457–458</ce:intra-ref>
</ce:index-entry>
...
```

Output File:

```
    \item Acceptance test\pid{idxB978-0-12-801507-0.00017-1.st0040<tab>00017}
    \pid{idxB978-0-12-801507-0.00017-1.sp0020<tab>00017}
    \pid{idxB978-0-12-801507-0.00017-1.sp0025<tab>00017}
    \pid{idxB978-0-12-801507-0.00017-1.st0055<tab>00017}, 
    \hyperpage{452-455}, \hyperpage{453}, \hyperpage{455}, \hyperpage{457-458}
```

Trying to Update:

```
<xsl:template match="ce:index-sec/ce:index-entry">
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&#10;\item </xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ce:index-heading"/>
```

Updated from:

```
       <xsl:for-each select="ce:intra-ref">
      <xsl:text>\pid{idx</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@xlink:href"/><xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
      <xsl:if test="position()=last()">
         <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">, </xsl:text>        
      </xsl:if>
       </xsl:for-each>
```

Updated to:

```
    <xsl:call-template name="do-entries"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Now the OUTPUT seems like:

```
\item Acceptance test\pid{idxpii:B978-0-12-801507-0.00017-1#st0040}
\pid{idxpii:B978-0-12-801507-0.00017-1#sp0020}
\pid{idxpii:B978-0-12-801507-0.00017-1#sp0025}
\pid{idxpii:B978-0-12-801507-0.00017-1#st0055}, 452–455, 453$f$, 455$f$, 457–458
```

I need to change the values **pii:B978-0-12-801507-0.00017-1#st0040** into **idxB978-0-12-801507-0.00017-1.st0040<tab>00017**.

Can anyone help me on this one?

Comment: Can you show us the rest of the stylesheet, please?

Comment: @Borodin: Its contain  more than thousand lines... I am not sure that I can able to write it here?

Comment: Do the "*output file*" represent the desired output?

Comment: @ssr1012 Please post a minimized. but **complete** examples of your input XML, XSLT and the requested output. Currently your question is incomprehensible.

Comment: It would help everyone, including you, if you wrote some proper sentences that describe your situation. All you have posted is the contents of some files and some curt captions. It may be hard to imagine that others don't know all about your situation but, really, *“Output File”*  could mean what you currently have that is wrong, or it could mean what you're trying to achieve. I can't understand “Trying to Update”* at all. It's a fraction of an XSLT stylesheet. Is it wrong? How is it wrong? Or perhaps your *goal* is to update a stylesheet according to some rules?

Comment: @Borodin: My sincere apologies for limitation asking on my question. I am simply expect the answers but I realize how hard to understand my question. I am a very very new in this platform (XSLT) just trying to learn on the same. Thanks for your response and obviously you are all my superiors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do what you ask

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:ce="http:/example.com/ce"
  xmlns:xlink="http:/example.com/xlink"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ce:index-entry">
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&#10;\item </xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ce:index-heading"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ce:intra-ref"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ce:intra-ref">
      <xsl:with-param name="hyperpage" select="1" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ce:index-heading">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ce:intra-ref">
    <xsl:param name="hyperpage" select="0" />

    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$hyperpage = 0">

        <xsl:variable name="pid" select="concat('idx', substring-after(@xlink:href, ':'))" />

        <xsl:variable name="pre" select="substring-before($pid, '#')" />

        <xsl:variable name="post" select="substring-after($pid, '#')" />

        <xsl:variable name="f5">
          <xsl:call-template name="field-n">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$pre"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="n" select="5"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:text>\pid{</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($pre, '.', $post)" />
        <xsl:text>&#x09;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($f5, '.')"/>
        <xsl:text>}&#x0A;</xsl:text>

      </xsl:when>

      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('\hyperpage{', child::text(), '}')" />
        <xsl:if test="following-sibling::ce:intra-ref">
          <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:otherwise>

    </xsl:choose>

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text/text()" name="field-n">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="n"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$n = 1">
          <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, '-')"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:call-template name="field-n">
          <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, '-')"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="n" select="$n - 1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
\item Acceptance test\pid{idxB978-0-12-801507-0.00017-1.st0040  00017}
\pid{idxB978-0-12-801507-0.00017-1.sp0020   00017}
\pid{idxB978-0-12-801507-0.00017-1.sp0025   00017}
\pid{idxB978-0-12-801507-0.00017-1.st0055   00017}
\hyperpage{452–455}, \hyperpage{453}, \hyperpage{455}, \hyperpage{457–458}
```